# Connecting to Azure Service bus using spring-cloud-azure-starter-servicebus-jms

Tags: spring-cloud, spring-jms, spring-cloud-azure

I am trying to follow microsoft documentation on connecting to azure service bus using spring-cloud-azure-starter-servicebus-jms.

[Ref](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/java/spring-framework/configure-spring-boot-starter-java-app-with-azure-service-bus?source=recommendations&tabs=use-a-service-bus-topic) but no luck .

Pom file  :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.4</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.demo</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.3-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>springcloud-servicebus-1</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.azure.spring</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-azure-starter-servicebus-jms</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.azure.spring</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-azure-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>4.6.0</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Java Code

```
package com.example.demo;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.jms.annotation.EnableJms;
import org.springframework.jms.annotation.JmsListener;
import org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableJms
public class Sample implements CommandLineRunner {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Sample.class);
    private static final String TOPIC_NAME = "loan-app";
    private static final String SUBSCRIPTION_NAME = "loan-app-sub";

    @Autowired
    private JmsTemplate jmsTemplate;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Sample.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) {
        LOGGER.info("Sending message");
        jmsTemplate.convertAndSend(TOPIC_NAME, "Hello Word");
    }

    @JmsListener(destination = TOPIC_NAME, containerFactory = "topicJmsListenerContainerFactory", subscription = SUBSCRIPTION_NAME)
    public void receiveMessage(String message) {
        LOGGER.info("Message received: {}", message);
    }

}
```

Error :

---

APPLICATION FAILED TO START

---

Description:

Field jmsTemplate in com.example.demo.Sample required a bean of type 'org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
- @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Spring Cloud Azure to Spring Boot version mapping](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/wiki/Spring-Versions-Mapping) shows that:

1. `Spring Cloud Azure 4.x` is compatible with `Spring Boot 2.x`.
2. `Spring Cloud Azure 5.x` is compatible with `Spring Boot 3.x`.

Now you are using `Spring Boot 3.0.4` with `Spring Cloud Azure 4.6.0`. They are not compatible. You have 2 options:

1. Option 1: Change `spring-boot-starter-parent`'s version from `3.0.4` to `2.7.8`.
2. Option 2: Change `spring-cloud-azure-dependencies`' version from `4.6.0` to `5.0.0`.